# pandas dataFrame joining error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have the below dataFrame:

```
columnName |            columnText              |       columnTextContents
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Linda      | [{age:45, category:technical},     | [{city:Mexico,type:member}]
           |   {age:55, category:nontechnical}] |  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Richeal    | [{age:65, category:technical}]     | [{city:Mexico,type:member}]
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

in above dataFrame second and third dataFrame is listOfDict and i want to recreate it into below dataFrame:

```
columnName | age  |  category    |  city    | type
--------------------------------------------------------
Linda      | 45   | technical    | Mexico   | member
--------------------------------------------------------
Linda      | 55   | nontechnical | NaN      | NaN
--------------------------------------------------------
Richeal    | 65   | technical    | Mexico   | member
--------------------------------------------------------
```

i have written below piece of code and its not generating expected outptut:

```
for k, v in zip(columnDataDF["columnText"].iteritems(), columnDataDF["columnTextContents"].iteritems()):
    tempDF = tempDF.append(pd.concat([pd.DataFrame.from_dict(k[1]), pd.DataFrame.from_dict(v[1])], axis=1))

columnDataDF = columnDataDF.drop('columnText', 1)
columnDataDF = columnDataDF.drop('columnTextContents', 1).join(tempDF)
```

below is output generated for above piece of code:

```
columnName | age  |  category    |  city    | type
--------------------------------------------------------
Linda      | 45   | technical    | Mexico   | member
--------------------------------------------------------
Linda      | 65   | technical    | Mexico   | member
--------------------------------------------------------
Richeal    |  55  | nontechnical | NaN      | NaN
--------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please read the sections on [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to format code blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You lose track of the original index when you create and modify your `tempDF`. Then the join will fail, because it doesn't properly match the indices.

One way around this, is to manually keep track of the indices, and assign it to the final `tempDF`. The index can be found as `k[0]` or `v[0]`.
The following may work:

```
index = []
for k, v in zip(columnDataDF["columnText"].iteritems(),
                columnDataDF["columnTextContents"].iteritems()):
    index.extend([k[0]] * len(k[1]))
    tempDF = tempDF.append(pd.concat([pd.DataFrame.from_dict(k[1]),
                                      pd.DataFrame.from_dict(v[1])], 
                                     axis=1))
tempDF.index = index
```